# Django Table Join

Tags: django, database, join, orm

I am going over the django join on to get some query set.
I have declared two model like this

```
class PortService(models.Model):
    port=models.IntegerField()
    service=models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('port','service'),)

class ServiceDefects(models.Model):
    port=models.ForeignKey('PortService')
    defect_id=models.TextField()
    defect_description=models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        unique_together=(('port','defect_id'),)
```

I want to get all the entry of ServiceDefects class which has a port number of 80 and service named 'Apache'. For this I wrote the query like this:

```
ServiceDefects.objects.filter(portservice__port=80).filter(portservice__service='Apache')
```

Any Help?? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The foreign key field is called `port`, not `portservice`, so you should do:

```
ServiceDefects.objects.filter(port__port=80).filter(port__service='Apache')
```

You might prefer to put both arguments in a single `filter()`:

```
ServiceDefects.objects.filter(port__port=80, port__service='Apache')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write both conditions in a single filter:

```
ServiceDefects.objects.filter(port__port=80, port__service='Apache')
```